# Не обрабатывает ошибку xhr js

Tags: javascript

https://youtu.be/eKCD9djJQKc?t=680 делаю 1 в 1 как на данном примере, но у автора, срабатывает ошибка если поломать ссылку, а у меня нет. Подскажите, и за чего не срабатывает ошибка, если сломать ссылку. Пересматривал код уже 4 раза.

```js
const requestURL = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users';

const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest()

xhr.open('GET', requestURL);

xhr.responseType = 'json'

xhr.onload = () => {
   console.log(xhr.response);
}

xhr.onerror = () => {
   console.log(xhr.response);
 }

xhr.send()
```

Answer (score 1):

Что скрывается за словами "если поломать ссылку", известно только Вам.

```js
const requestURL = 'https://WRONG_URL.typicode.com/users';

const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest()

xhr.open('GET', requestURL);

xhr.responseType = 'json'

xhr.onload = () => {
   console.log('load', xhr.response);
}

xhr.onerror = () => {
   console.log('error', xhr.response);
 }

xhr.send()
```

Comment: Имеется ввиду если изменить какой то символ, или подставить другую ссылку. Странно, потому что у автора: https://youtu.be/eKCD9djJQKc?t=680 запись 1 в 1 как у меня. Но, у меня не срабатывает ошибка, как у него(

Comment: @ИгорьСолодовник вам вот привели пример с ошибкой в URL все работает (error null)